# Android : Slow layout loading

Tags: android, android-layout

I have noticed lately that my layouts are opening quite slowly. It takes ~ 1 - 1,5 sec to open one specific layout. My guess why it loads so slowly is because of the high amount of layout items and visuals. Is there a way of fixing the layout load time or just loading all the layouts in background while opening app.

**Here's my xml for the slowest loading layout:**

[Layout.xml](https://pastebin.com/gm8pLXxv)

Comment: Consider using `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Your layout does not look very complicated and is not much nested. Are you sure are not doing something else in onCreate() which makes the Activity slow

Comment: My onCreate() basically refers all the layout items with findViewById() and calls 3 simple methods : loadData() (gets all kind of values), setGUI() (applies images on the layout items) and updateDisplay() (applies values to TextView). That's all more or less

Comment: Check your image resources, make sure that every one of them resized for specific dpi and grouped with specific drawable folders like drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi etc... Do not put your big images into drawable folder directly. And Do not use big images into small area imageviews, resize and make them smaller to fit the area.

Comment: @oguzhand I tried resizing the resources and it made the layout load a lot faster, but I lost image quality which I really need. Are there other options?

Comment: @K.Bowman you need to find a balance between quality and performance. You can use webp or png formats, if you have transparent background in your images. Otherwise, you can use jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing layout hierarchy. The layout files might have had long hierarchies. If you are using  tag in your XML files, try replacing it with .
More info - https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

To improving Layout Performance in your android apps, you want to consider the following

- Optimizing Layout Hierarchies
- Re-using Layouts with
- Loading Views OnDemand

more details https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts